# Can someone help me fix this WooCommerce Wordpress typo?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue with WooCommerce on Wordpress where the default sorting bar on the left (on the store page) has a typo be default and I'm unable to change it.

[image: Screenshot of the left nav bar]

I don't have access to the backend/hosting, only the Wordpress editing backend itself.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.
Thanks.

I have searched the Woocommerce settings high and low and cannot find how to change the text.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but you should be able to use gettext:

```
function translate_wc_typo( $translated, $text, $context, $domain ) {
    if ( 'woocommerce' == $domain && 'Brows By Categories' == $text ) {
        $fixed= 'Browse By Categories';
    }

    return $fixed;
}
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 'translate_wc_typo', 10, 4 );
```

If this doesn't work, first make sure it's actually using the `woocommerce` text domain.

EDIT: ---------

Sorry, this requires code changes so you'd need to put it in your own plugin and install it on the site. Alternatively, look into a translation plugin like Polylang.

Comment: Ah, sorry, just realized you said you can't change the code. In that case, look into the Polylang plugin, or another translation plugin.